# How to make a for loop where the variables I loop throw are similar except the number at the end?

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have a lot of arrays where the index number of the array is the same as the end of my variable name. I want to be able to run a for loop, and assign the CropGrapes variables to the Grapes array, i haved tried but can´t seem to find out how.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Tilemaps;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class CropHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

// Sprites of Grapes    
public Tile CropGrapes1;
public Tile CropGrapes2;
public Tile CropGrapes3;
public Tile CropGrapes4;
public Tile CropGrapes5;
public Tile CropGrapes6;
public Tile[] Grapes;

public void Start()
{
    Grapes[0] = CropGrapes1;
    Grapes[1] = CropGrapes2;
    Grapes[2] = CropGrapes3;
    Grapes[3] = CropGrapes4;
    Grapes[4] = CropGrapes5;
    Grapes[5] = CropGrapes6;

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        Grapes[i] = CropGrapes_i
    }
}
```

I am using Unity and coding in c#

Comment: What's the type of `Grapes` and `CropGrapes...`? Post all code required.

Comment: can you insert `CropGrapes` to array?

Comment: I dont have a variable thats named CropsGrapes, i am trying to write the first couple of lines of code in the Start() function with a loop instead of the repetition of code.

Comment: Where is the data coming from initially? What class is it in?

Comment: I have updated the code, so its all there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection to get a list of all the fields and filter them by name. You could then parse the name in some way to get the index number, assign the field info and the number to an anonymous type, loop over them and use the `GetValue` method to get the value.

Try something like this:

```
class Class1
{
    public Tile CropGrapes1;
    public Tile CropGrapes2;
    public Tile CropGrapes3;
    public Tile CropGrapes4;
    public Tile CropGrapes5;
    public Tile CropGrapes6;
    public Tile[] Grapes = new Tile[6];

    public void Start()
    {
        var fields = this.GetType()
            .GetFields()
            .Where(f => f.Name.StartsWith("CropGrapes"))
            .Select(f => new { Field = f, Index = int.Parse(f.Name.Substring("CropGrapes".Length)) })
            .OrderBy(f => f.Index);

        for (int i = 0; i < fields.Count(); i++)
        {
            Grapes[i] = fields.Single(f => f.Index == i + 1).Field.GetValue(this) as Tile;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was exactly what i was looking for, thank you, i am not working on it right now, but i will try it out tomorrov

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as accepted if it solved the problem.